# Errors Integrating Doctrine Into Zend Framework

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

When trying to run a simple command $msg = $this->_em->find("Entities\Message", 1); in my IndexController I get the following errors:

```
( ! ) Warning: class_parents() [function.class-parents]: Class Entities\Message does not exist and could not be loaded in C:\wamp\www\KosherOven\library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  372272  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:27
3   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )    ..\Application.php:366
4   0.0919  5254864 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
5   0.1088  6406328 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch( )    ..\Front.php:954
6   0.1218  6758576 Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:295
7   0.1219  6761896 IndexController->indexAction( ) ..\Action.php:513
8   0.1219  6761992 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->find( ) ..\IndexController.php:16
9   0.1225  6764176 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository( )    ..\EntityManager.php:344
10  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata( ) ..\EntityManager.php:567
11  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor( )    ..\EntityManager.php:251
12  0.1226  6764272 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:169
13  0.1226  6764456 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:245
14  0.1226  6764608 class_parents ( )   ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:222

( ! ) Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\KosherOven\library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  372272  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:27
3   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )    ..\Application.php:366
4   0.0919  5254864 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
5   0.1088  6406328 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch( )    ..\Front.php:954
6   0.1218  6758576 Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:295
7   0.1219  6761896 IndexController->indexAction( ) ..\Action.php:513
8   0.1219  6761992 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->find( ) ..\IndexController.php:16
9   0.1225  6764176 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository( )    ..\EntityManager.php:344
10  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata( ) ..\EntityManager.php:567
11  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor( )    ..\EntityManager.php:251
12  0.1226  6764272 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:169
13  0.1226  6764456 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:245
14  0.1247  6774560 array_reverse ( )   ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:222

( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\KosherOven\library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  372272  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:27
3   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )    ..\Application.php:366
4   0.0919  5254864 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
5   0.1088  6406328 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch( )    ..\Front.php:954
6   0.1218  6758576 Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:295
7   0.1219  6761896 IndexController->indexAction( ) ..\Action.php:513
8   0.1219  6761992 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->find( ) ..\IndexController.php:16
9   0.1225  6764176 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository( )    ..\EntityManager.php:344
10  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata( ) ..\EntityManager.php:567
11  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor( )    ..\EntityManager.php:251
12  0.1226  6764272 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:169
13  0.1226  6764456 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:245

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Message in C:\wamp\www\KosherOven\application\models\Entities\Message.php on line 9
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  372272  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application->run( )    ..\index.php:27
3   0.0918  5254808 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run( )    ..\Application.php:366
4   0.0919  5254864 Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch( )  ..\Bootstrap.php:97
5   0.1088  6406328 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch( )    ..\Front.php:954
6   0.1218  6758576 Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:295
7   0.1219  6761896 IndexController->indexAction( ) ..\Action.php:513
8   0.1219  6761992 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->find( ) ..\IndexController.php:16
9   0.1225  6764176 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository( )    ..\EntityManager.php:344
10  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata( ) ..\EntityManager.php:567
11  0.1225  6764240 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor( )    ..\EntityManager.php:251
12  0.1226  6764272 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:169
13  0.1257  6774344 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->newClassMetadataInstance( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:260
14  0.1301  7172352 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata->__construct( )  ..\ClassMetadataFactory.php:351
15  0.1301  7172592 ReflectionClass->__construct( ) ..\ClassMetadata.php:67
16  0.1302  7172896 Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader->loadClass( )   ..\ClassLoader.php:0
17  0.1305  7182920 require( 'C:\wamp\www\KosherOven\application\models\Entities\Message.php' ) ..\ClassLoader.php:148
```

Here is my doctrine bootstrap code:

```
protected function _initDoctrine()
{
    /* Autoload classes */
    require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
    $classLoader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine');
    $classLoader->register();
    // load the doctrine class loader for Symfony library components
    $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', 'Doctrine');
    $classLoader->register();
    $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
    $classLoader->register();

    /* Choose cache */

    if (APPLICATION_ENV == "development") {
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
    } else {
        //$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
    }

    $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);

    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/doctrine/Mapping');
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
    $config->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/Proxies');
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

    if (APPLICATION_ENV == "development") {
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
    } else {
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
    }

    $configObj = $this->_initConfig();

    $connectionOptions = array(
        'driver'   => $configObj->database->adapter,
        'dbname'   => $configObj->database->params->dbname,
        'host'     => $configObj->database->params->host,
        'user'     => $configObj->database->params->username,
        'password' => $configObj->database->params->password
    );
    $em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

    Zend_Registry::set('em', $em);
}
```

I am using Doctrine 2.0.4.

I can't think of any other info to provide, but I would be happy to add more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the following class in `application/models/Entities/Message.php`

```
namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Message
{
    // ...
```

---

Also, I'm not sure about this line

```
// load the doctrine class loader for Symfony library components
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', 'Doctrine');
```

Isn't that saying the `Symfony` namespace / folder is in the `Doctrine` directory?

**Edit:** My guess would be it should look like this

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony');
```

---

### UPDATE

I think I see what's missing. You aren't telling the annotation driver where to find your entities.

I think this line

> $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/doctrine/Mapping');

should be

```
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Entities');
```

See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html

I highly recommend you check out the Bisna integration from Guilherme Blanco - https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2

I also have a sort of ZF/Doctrine2 app skeleton here that you're welcome to look at - https://github.com/philBrown/ZFDoctrineSkeleton

Comment: You mean 'application/models/Entities/Message.php' should contain the code generated by Doctrine? If so, then it is. And I think the second thing is needed for the Symfony components used in the cli tool.

Comment: @moteutsch No, the generated code (proxies) go in `application/Proxies` and you shouldn't need to worry about them. As you're using the annotation driver, you need to create actual classes for your entities.

Comment: If you want your entities straight in the `models/` folder then you have to use Zend's resource autoloader.

Comment: @Cobby No they don't. They've set the Doctrine ClassLoader to find `Entities` namespaced classes in `applications/models/Entities`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're not pushing your Doctrine, Symfony, and Entities class loaders onto the Zend autoloader:

```
require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$autoloader = \Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$symfonyAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony');
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($symfonyAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Symfony');

$doctrineAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine');
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($doctrineAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Doctrine');

$entityAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($entityAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Entities');
```

Comment: He's registering them instead. PHP can handle multiple autoloaders.